# Understanding AJAX Post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to understand the **HTTP POST** request sent by jQuery's `.ajax()` or `.post()` functions. What I don't get is **why is there a 'datatype' parameter for the data sent from the server?**

What kind of information will be sent from the server in a POST request?

It makes sense to have data from server from GET but I thought POST request is for posting data.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Smells like homework

Comment: Excellent reading material -->  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: sounds like dev tools :)

Comment: Every request generates some response, even a POST.

Comment: Have you thought about coding an AJAX Post call and trying to manipulate the callback data? *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Comment: The datatype parameter specifies the data type such as XML or JSON. When you make any request to a server, whether it be POST or GET you get information back, you get back response headers and depending on you're doing the server may send back an newly generated id of the object you tried to create for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between POST and GET is that Data sent with a GET request is shown in your Browser's URL thus making GET request less recommended send Data use by the server. Get request are normaly used to retrieve Data from the server, has POST request dont show your Data in your browser's URL thus making more suitable for passing variable that must be handle by the server such as Usernames, Password or more sensible information.

Hope this help!

Comment: BOTH request can answer the user with data such as XML, Text, JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The server will return a string no matter what.
And by default, xmlhttprequest send you back this string in the callback.

jQuery uses this value internally to save you some time: if you precise 'json' it will automatically parse the string and you'll directly get a javascript object in your response callback. Same kind of work with 'xml'.

Answer (score 0):

POST and GET are simply methods of information transportation TO the server. Once the server gets this info it sends back a response which can be formatted in a variety of ways.

Setting:

```
type: 'GET'
```

in an AJAX call does NOT mean "get data from server"

When you set dataType

```
dataType: 'json'
```

it means that the server is responding with a JSON string so jQuery is going to convert it into a usable and accessible object for you.